# How is 情けは人の為ならず used?

Tags: expressions

Is it used in the positive sense "you should do good things for others! good things will happen to you as well" or rather, negative "good things are rooted in selfish motivations", or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 「[情]{なさ}けは[人]{ひと}の[為]{ため}ならず」

If I remember correctly what I learned in high school, there is a huge discrepancy between what this proverb originally meant and what many people today **think** it means.

***Original meaning***: The first of the two interpretations you listed. "Do good things for others and good things will eventually happen to you."

***Common misinterpretation***: "Show (too much) mercy and it will not bring good results to that person in the end."  In other words, "Be on the strict side to others if you want them to succeed in the long run."

Your second interpretation "Good things are rooted in selfish motivations." appears to be your own.

Comment: This is one of the famous "misunderstood proverbs," and roughly half of the people believe in the wrong interpretation ([source](http://www.bunka.go.jp/publish/bunkachou_geppou/2012_03/series_08/series_08.html)).